# Using sed in php-file

Tags: php, sed, lighttpd

I have some simple php sites on my Raspberry Pi, so I can do things in the browser and don't have to login there with `putty`. I installed `php5` and `lighttpd`.

Most things work fine (I had some trouble with permissions) but I don't seem to get this working.

```
<?php    
echo shell_exec("tail -n 50 test_all.log|sed '{:q;N;s/\n/<br>/g;t q}'");
?>
<form action="index.php">
<input type="submit" Value="Back">
</form>
```

It works without the `sed`-part and `tail -n 50 test_all.log|sed '{:q;N;s/\n/<br>/g;t q}'` works as user `www-data` in the console, but in the browser I just get the back-button.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps try a `sudo -u www-data tail -n 50 test_all.log|tail -n 50 test_all.log|sed '{:q;N;s/\n/<br>/g;t q}'` as maybe the apache service uses another user like http?

Comment: doesn't work. Using `whoami` also shows me www-data

Comment: you should replace `\n` with `\\n` inside double quote.

Comment: thanks, I thought it was just some stupid minor mistake, but I couldn't put my finger on it